# fragments overlapped , need solution to maximize and minimize fragments

Tags: android, for-loop, mono

Can anyone tell me the solution for below problem.
I have created simple chat application in which i want to open multiple chat windows using fragments.
I have done with this but now problem is i am not able to seperate that chat fragments, all gets overlaps with one another.
Please suggest me the solution so that i can make these fragments seperate with minimize and maximize buttons.
If you provide code snippet it will be helpfull for me because i am new to adroid developement.

Thanks & ragards,
Anand Jagtap.

i have done by using tab listener and storing the chat history in static variable.

```
/// <summary>
/// Listener that handles the selection of a tab in the user interface
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class TabListener<T> : Java.Lang.Object, ActionBar.ITabListener
    where T : Fragment
{
    private T _fragment;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the tab listener
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fragment"></param>
    public TabListener(T fragment)
    {
        _fragment = fragment;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the reselection of the tab
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tab"></param>
    /// <param name="ft"></param>
    public void OnTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the fragment when the tab was selected
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tab"></param>
    /// <param name="ft"></param>
    public void OnTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (tab.Text == "Users")
        {
            fragment = Global.UserFragment;
        }
        else
        {
            fragment = Global.ChatWindows.FirstOrDefault(chat => chat.User.Name == tab.Text);
            tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.message);
        }

        Global.CurrentFragment = fragment;
        FragmentManager fm = Global.QActivity.FragmentManager;
        fm.BeginTransaction().Add(Resource.Id.Frame_container, fragment, tab.Text).Commit();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the fragment when the tab was deselected
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tab"></param>
    /// <param name="ft"></param>
    public void OnTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (tab.Text == "Users")
        {
            fragment = Global.UserFragment;
        }
        else
        {
            fragment = Global.ChatWindows.FirstOrDefault(chat => chat.User.Name == tab.Text);
            tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.QChatOffline);
        }

        FragmentManager fm = Global.QActivity.FragmentManager;
        fm.BeginTransaction().Remove(fragment).Commit();
    }
}
```

private void StartChat(string userName, bool selectedFromList)
        {
            try
            {
                User user = GetUserByName(userName);
                ChatFragment chatFragment = Global.ChatWindows.Find(chatWindow => chatWindow.User.Name == user.Name);
                var ft = this.activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                if (chatFragment == null)
                {
                    chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
                    chatFragment.User = user;
                    chatFragment.CurrentUser = Global.Host.Username;

```
                var chatTab = this.activity.ActionBar.NewTab();
                chatFragment.TabListener = new TabListener<ChatFragment>(chatFragment);
                chatTab.SetTabListener(chatFragment.TabListener);
                chatTab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.message);
                chatTab.SetText(userName);
                // Add the new tab to the action bar
                this.activity.ActionBar.AddTab(chatTab);
                ft.Add(Resource.Id.Frame_container, chatFragment, user.Name);
                Global.ChatWindows.Add(chatFragment);

                this.activity.ActionBar.SelectTab(chatTab);

                Global.CurrentFragment = chatFragment;
                ft.Commit();
            }
            else
            {
                int index = Global.ChatWindows.FindIndex(chat => chat.User.Name == chatFragment.User.Name);
                ActionBar.Tab tab = this.activity.ActionBar.GetTabAt(index + 1);
                tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.message);
                if (selectedFromList)
                {
                    ft.Remove(chatFragment);
                    ft.Commit();
                    Global.CurrentFragment = chatFragment;

                    try
                    {
                        var fragmentTransaction = this.activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                        this.activity.ActionBar.SelectTab(tab);
                        fragmentTransaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ft.Remove(chatFragment);
                    ft.Add(Resource.Id.Frame_container, chatFragment, user.Name);
                    ft.Commit();
                }
            }

            chatFragment.ChatHistory.Add(new ChatHistory()
            {
                FirstPartColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Red,
                FirstPartMessage = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"),
                SecondPartMessage = String.Format(" {0} is {1}.", user.Name, m_chatWindowManager.GetStatusText(user.Status).Replace("%@RN@%", "\r\n" + "\r\n")),
                SecondPartColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Red
            });

            Global.ChatStarted = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ((QChatActivity)this.activity).ShowMessage("Failed StartChat(string userName) for user " + userName + " Exception : " + exception.Message + exception.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android there is no support for minimize or maximize the screen, instead of that you can make alert boxes as a activity for chatting in separate windows.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcomeToIM"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMsg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
        android:text="Contacts"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Type a Message"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:textColor="#000000" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh for your reply. I have only one activity which can manage the send and recieve of messages. and two fragment classes one is for showing users list and another for chat. from user list fragment i am opening as many fragments of chat. is it possible for you to provide the code snippet for opening fragments runtime in new frame and swapping betwwen them. Thanks

Comment: i have done this using action bar tabs and fragments but now challenge is how to switch between tabs without loosing their previous states. I have used tablistner for same but not able to preserve the prevoius state of fragments.